# Get checkbox value in grid cell javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one grid with a checkbox on cell[6], I tried to get the state of this check box using a lot of methods, like:

- .is(':checked');
- .prop('checked');
- .val()
- .value
- .checked
- ...

The html of

```
<tr>
    <td hidden id='tableRowId'> + obj.itemId + </td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='sel' class='chcktbl' id='ckh' value=' + obj.partNumber + '/></td>
    <td> + obj.partNumber + </td>
    <td> + quantidade + </td>
    <td> + txtDesconto +  %</td>
    <td> + obj.leadTime + </td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='sel' class='chcktbl' id='ckhLeadTime' onclick='leadTimeStateChanged(this)' value='0' /></td>
    <td><input type='date' class='form-control form-control-sm' id='txtDataEntrega' onchange='onFocusOutDataEntrega(this)' /></td>
    <td><a data-value=' + obj.partNumber + ' onclick=GetDetalhesItemTotvs(' + obj.partNumber + ',  + quantidade + , + txtDesconto + ) href='javascript:void(0)' class='btnEdit'>Detalhes</a></td>
</tr>
```

My js code:

```
function leadTimeStateChanged(checkbox) {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        checkbox.setAttribute('value', '1');
        checkbox.setAttribute('checked', true);
    }
    else {
        checkbox.setAttribute('value', '0');
        checkbox.setAttribute('checked', false);
    }
}

  function xxxx() {
    var rowIndex = 0;
    var t = document.getElementById('itensTBody');
    $("#itensTBody tr").each(function () {

        alert(t.rows[rowIndex].cells[6].val());
        alert(t.rows[rowIndex].cells[6].value);
        alert(t.rows[rowIndex].cells[6].checked);
        alert(t.rows[rowIndex].cells[6].prop('checked'));
        alert(t.rows[rowIndex].cells[6].is(':checked'));



        var tmpItem = {
            PropostaItemId: $(t.rows[rowIndex].cells[0]).text(),
            PartNumber: $(t.rows[rowIndex].cells[2]).text(),
            Quantidade: parseInt($(t.rows[rowIndex].cells[3]).text()),
            Desconto: parseFloat($(t.rows[rowIndex].cells[4]).text()),
            MostraLeadTime: $(t.rows[rowIndex].cells[6]).is(':checked'),
            //DataDeEntrega: $(t.rows[rowIndex].cells[7]).text(),
        }
        obj.ItensProposta.push(tmpItem);
        rowIndex++;
    }); 
  }
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: yeap, I use jquery to get some textbox values and to to execute some ajax functions

Answer (score 0):

Just for retrieving the checkbox's value:

```
    //...
    alert($('input', t.rows[rowIndex].cells[6]).is(":checked"));
    //...
```